# WordPress | Woocommerce | use "category display type" in if statement

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In category display type u can choose between (default, products, subcategories, both) options.
Is there any way to make an if statement that uses those values?

I would like todo something like the below but i'm having a hard time figuring out how u can check for those values.

Now i have something like the below but that requires me to do this for hundreds of categories

```
<?php if (is_product_category('979') || is_product_category('979')) then do something ?>
```

So i'm actually looking for something like the below

```
<?php if (category is display type ('products')) then do something ?>
```

So if anyone know a way to filter using display type that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching i found a solution in the code below which checks if your category display view is set in my case as products.

```
        $cat_id = $queried_object->term_id;
        $test = array(
            'hide_empty' => false, // also retrieve terms which are not used yet
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                'key'       => 'display_type',
                'value'     => 'products',
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                )
            ),
        );
        $terms = get_terms( $test );
            foreach ($terms as $product_page) {
            if ($product_page->term_id === $cat_id) {
        $category_value = $product_page->term_id;
        } }
```

Now u can use something like $cat_id === $category_value
Whenever a category page is set to display_type products it will return a true

If needed u can change this to any of the other options as shown below.

```
                'value'     => 'subcategories',
                'value'     => '', // <-- this is the default
                'value'     => 'both',  // <-- this is both options
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the function `get_term_meta`.

```php
// Get the current category ID;
$category_id = get_queried_object_id();

// Get the meta data using the ID;
$term_vals = get_term_meta( $category_id );

// One of the values is display type, with the value at index 0;
// this can be products, subcategories, or both
if ( $term_vals[ 'display_type' ][ 0 ] === 'products' ) {
    // Do your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where whoocommerce posts are stored, you could do this via basic Wordpress post queries, via:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
  'category_name' => 'your_category',
  'tag' => 'your_tag'
);

$arr_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ($arr_posts->have_posts()) {
  while ($arr_posts->have_posts()) {
    echo $arr_posts->the_post();
      // Echo out content of each post, but here you may do whatever you want
      the_content();
      }
    } else {
    echo "<p class='error'>No posts fulfill your search criteria!<p>";
    }
```

Note that you can adapt your query parameters, by specifying additional query criteria in the $args array (or take out any of the ones I provided, if you please).

I've added an error class to your error feedback such that you can style it in CSS as you may please (color:red; etc). Again, this example works if your product posts are stored in the wp_posts database. If not, you may do something similar, by querying in the corresponding database holding your product posts.

Just found this https://wp-staging.com/in-which-database-table-is-woocommerce-storing-products/, so the code above should definitely work.

Comment: Instead of matching data from wp_posts i'm trying to look inside wp_termmeta and search for meta_key 'display_type' that has a value of 'products' inside meta_value. And it needs to check true or false against the currently displayed WooCommerce product-category.

Comment: According to the link I've sent you above, you should be able to then use 'post_type' => 'products' and retrieve currently_displayed_category and use 'category_name' => 'currently_displayed_category'. Use these two query specifications in the $args array as described above, and it should work.

Comment: I tried your solution which didnt gave the right true or false. i also tried code below but didnt get it working exactly right yet
   $display_type_check = get_term_meta( get_the_ID(), 'products' );
                        $cat_id = $queried_object->term_id;
   $product_pagina = '';
   foreach ($display_type_check as $check_type) {
   $category_id = ($check_type->term_id);
   if ($check_type->term_id === $cat_id) {
   $product_pagina = 'goed';
   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

The answer from **@Tim Steel** is a good direction, but we can do it in a simpler way:

```
$category_id = get_queried_object_id();
if ($category_id) {
    $term_vals = get_term_meta($category_id, 'display_type', true);
    if ($term_vals === 'subcategories') {
        echo 'We are on subcategories';
    }
}
```